# call jar file or class file in my javascript for native mobile apps

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, jar

I am developing native mobile app in cordova(phonegap) with the help of visual studio 2013.I have setup all things and already build a demo project that works fine.Now I need to call a jar file or class file in my javascript code.I don't know whether it is possible or not.If possible then how?

I have already go through the following link..

[Can JavaScript use classes from a jar file (Non Internet Use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579750/can-javascript-use-classes-from-a-jar-file-non-internet-use)

[http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:*Extensions*:_Example_Code_:_Calling_Java_from_Javascript](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Extensions_:_Example_Code_:_Calling_Java_from_Javascript)